# Is this statement hold in Sn?

Tags: group-theory

statement : In the symmetric group Sn, any two element of the same order are   conjugate .

my try ; i was googlin it,, i was  found that let σ ,ρ ∈ Sn, be the two

permutation in Sn , then σ and ρ will conjugate if they have  same cycle

type.....from this theorem i can  conclude that,,any two  element of same order are conjugate in symmetric group Sn...

PLiz tell me whether im correct or not  and tell me the solution......

Comment: In $S_4$ do the permutations $(1\ 2)$ and $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)$ have the same order? Do they have the same cycle type? Are they conjugate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints. Take $n=4$.

1. Try computing $\sigma(1\,2)\sigma^{-1}$, where $\sigma\in S_4$.
2. What's the order of $(1\,2)(3\,4)$?

For instance, if $\sigma=(1\,2\,3)$, we have
$$
(1\,2\,3)(1\,2)(1\,3\,2)=(2\,3)=(\sigma(1)\,\sigma(2))
$$
Can you say the same for *every* $\sigma\in S_4$?

Comment: @egreg.....i have compute  the 1.   σ(12)σ-1 =(12)(34)(12) (34)(12) = (12)  ,,,,and for 2.    order of (12)(34)  will be  2,,,,but here im not getting whether it is conjugate or not ?

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh I added a further hint

Comment: thanks a lots @egreg,,,+1 and marked as an accepted answer